How does the game decide if you used the bio-beam for the "Disintegration Ray" achievement?
When I was playing this mod, the game gave me the achievement "Disintegration Ray" with the Anti-Bio Beam Mark II.
I couldn't find anything in the mod's code that would change the achievement requirements, so what exactly constitutes an Anti-Bio Beam weapon for the achievement?

I'm asking for technical information. What is required for the game to see a weapon as the anti-biobeam

Is there even any way to answer this without either getting an official developer response or reverse-engineering the game?

would making a bunch of mods with a modified weapon and seeing which ones give the achievement count as reverse engineering the game?

@Joachim I preferer my wording as there's an event that has nothing to do with the achievement which requires a weapon with the exact ID for the anti-bio beam, which given what I know about the game is not how the game decides what's an anti-biobeam for the slug ship achievement

The "Disintegration Ray" achievement is awarded when the game detects that the last crew member on an enemy ship was killed by the Anti-Bio Beam, identified by its unique ID. If a modded weapon uses the same ID as the Anti-Bio Beam, the game would consider it as the Anti-Bio Beam and grant the achievement when it kills the final enemy crew member.
So the game decides if you used the Anti-Bio Beam for the Disintegration Ray achievement based on:

The weapon ID of the Anti-Bio Beam.
The death of the last enemy crew member by this weapon.


No, that cannot be right, as the mod uses the ID "BEAM_BIO_2"

I just confirmed and the game does indeed give me the achievement with the Bio Beam 2

@Dave Does the mod also change the achievement code, to check for either id?

It doesn't, there's nothing I can see that would change that

no, it doesn't, not that I can find
